# Is good practice to UNION two fact tables?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two fact tables of the same type of events: `Incidents (Open)` and `Incidents (Closed)`.

Each one of these tables has a completely different Power Query process (one comes from SQL, the other from reading cvs files in a Sharepoint folder), and also have Incremental Refresh policies based on different columns.

Idealy I'd like to combine them both in the Power Query stage, but I don't find a way to do it and still keep the Incremental Refresh behavior.

I thought in putting the logic in a Dataflow, but there the Incremental Refresh works differently than in Desktop and I don't find a way to refresh properly reading from the Sharepoint folder.

I don't want to combine both queries in the Power Query stage because this turns into a completely new query, doubles used space in the model and increases the refresh time.

I was playing around with the `UNION` DAX function. Seems that it returns both tables unified pretty quick, but is this an accepted practice?

Could I use this DAX generated fact table in my model? Would it slow performance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION() is a DAX table function, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/union-function-dax. It's executed upon refresh only - just like any PowerQuery table or the calculated columns - and the resulting table becomes part of the data model. This means that it is static and doesn't recalculate on filter changes. So you don't have to expect performance issues. You'll likely have more trouble with combining your fact tables via a link table. If the data structure allows it, UNION() is your best option.